# How to remove the right element from array react?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I want to remove an element from my array when click on a specific row.
When I click on an element it does nothing or the last row gets deleted.

**I tried to remove the element like this:**

```
ondeleterow(e: any) {
  const array = [...this.state.fields.columns]; // make a separate copy of the array
  const index = array.indexOf(e.target.id);
  if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ fields: { columns: array }});
  }
}
```

**My array/json object looks like this:**

```
[ {index: 0, name: "person 1", age: 12},
  {index: 1, name: "person 2", age: 19},
  {index: 2, name: "person 3", age: 34},
]
```

My result should be when I click on a row with `ID=1` the row with `index: 1` gets deleted from my state array.
**I can't give them an Id because when I submit the json structure then does not get accepted.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like your `Array.splice` might be causing the issue here (because even though you created a new array, the objects in the array are still passed by reference).

I would recommend a completely different method of doing this operation which I've found to be far cleaner and robust.

First you have to add a unique `id` field to each row. (this is good practice in react anyway, instead of using index for keys).

```
ondeleterow(id: string) {
  return (e: any) => {
    const array = this.state.fields.column.filter(item => item.id != id)
    this.setState({ fields: { columns: array }});
  }
}
```

and when you're mapping over your rows, you can simply add the function to the `onClick` like this

```
<Row key={item.id} onClick={ondeleterow(item.id)} />
```

Comment: This won't work if the array is not sorted by the `index` key though

Comment: @molamk how so? I am simply filtering out all the rows that have the `index` as `event.target.id`. there is no mention of order here

Comment: @OP I would recommend you look at the edits and follow the second method I mentioned, it's better to use this than to depend on the index for uniqueness.

Comment: I was referring to your code before the edit (the first snippet in your answer). It's reasonable to assume that the array won't be sorted by the `index` key which will make it behave in the wrong way. The 2nd snippet is all good though

Comment: I don't understand...Event the first snippet should work, the `Array.filter` should work fine regardless of order. Can you please give me an example of when it would fail? I would prefer to remove the first part of my answer if it really is buggy code.

Comment: Say you have `[{index: 0, ...}, {index: 2, ...}, {index: 1, ...}]` and `id = 1`. Your firrst snippet will remove the `{index: 2, ...}`. The 2nd one will remove `{index: 1, ...}` as it should

Comment: I see..you're right, thank you..removing that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Never use **splice** in react especially with state. They directly mutate the data. Use non mutating operations like **slice**.

Your code should as follows

```
ondeleterow(e: any) {
 const array = [...this.state.fields.columns]; // make a separate copy of the array
 const index = array.indexOf(e.target.id);
 if (index !== -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({ fields: {
    columns: [ ...array.slice(0, index), ...array.slice(index + 1, array.length) ]
  }});
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This will allow you to create a new array with only the items you want based on a certain criteria. In this case, you want an array with items that have a different ID that the one you want to remove. So it will look like this

```js
// Actual processing
const filterByIndex = (arr, idx) => arr.filter(x => x.index !== idx);

// Your data
const json = [{
    index: 0,
    name: "person 1",
    age: 12
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    name: "person 2",
    age: 19
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    name: "person 3",
    age: 34
  },
];

// Printing the result
console.log(filterByIndex(json, 1));
```

## In your React app

```
ondeleterow(e: any) {
    const columns = this.state.fields.columns.filter(x => x.index !== e.target.id);
    this.setState({ fields: { columns }});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onDeleteRow(e) {
    const afterRemoval = this.setState.fields.columns.filter(item => item.index != e.target.id);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ fields: { ...prevState.fields, columns: afterRemoval } }));
}
```

The other solution above sets the `fields` field directly, It may work but will cause problem if `fields` has some other attribute other than `columns` (those attributes will get removed)